# REGEX extract two double number separated from hypen

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like:

```
 some foo text
 some foo
 1-2
 1.00-2.00
 3.21-1.23
 2.12-2.12
```

I have to check if the string format contains two numbers separated by hyphen.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: So which one did you choose?

Comment: I've noticed you don't like accepting answers or giving feedback. Not an attitude I like. Insomma, dovresti deciderti e magari aggiornare chi ti ha dato una mano, mi sembra il minimo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

`^\d+(\.\d+)?-\d+(\.\d+)?$`

Explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/lFNulb/1).

---

Using java you can create a method that checks whether your desired pattern exists or not:

```
public static boolean returnMatch(String input) {
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?-\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);

    return m1.find() ? true : false;
}
```

Now call it using:

```
System.out.println(returnMatch("some foo text"));  // false
System.out.println(returnMatch("1.00-2.00"));      // true
System.out.println(returnMatch("2.12-2.12"));      // true
System.out.println(returnMatch("10-20"));          // true
```

Comment: how can I modify the regex for check also integer numbers like 1-2

Comment: It already handles that scenario. Click the link in the answer, I've included examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regex for float is: `^[1-9]\d*\.\d+$` if decimals are optional : `^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`

Repeat it twice with hyphen in between:

```
`^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?-[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple Regex:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)-(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This solution assumes there is *always* a decimal part present (at least one digit). Demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VfiydF/3).

- `\d` is a digit
- `\d+` is at least one digit
- `\.` matches a dot (`.`) literally
- `()` is a capturing group
- `(?:\.\d+)?` is a non-capturing group which optionally matches the decimal part

Don't forget the proper escaping in Java `String regex = "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)-(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)";`

In case one or more spaced or blank characters appear between the dash and numbers, [use](https://regex101.com/r/qePLVD/2):

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*-\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Comment: the string can contain also integer number separated from hypen. I have to get also 1-2 string

Comment: @michele You must include this information. See my edited answer.